# Does ArcPy work for Engine or Server the same as Desktop?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-server, arcgis-engine

I am contemplating a project where there is not going to be access to ArcGIS Desktop and I amwondering if ArcGIS Engine and/or ArcGIS Server install ArcPy and Python?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Python gets installed with every product level, and yes, ArcPy is installed and will work in both, including things like map automation.